# How to get arbitrarily high in Thief games?

Tags: thief-the-dark-project

I want to know how to get arbitrarily high in Thief games. I once read about this technique. I would say it looked something like flying. It does not seem like what developers wanted, so I would say it is a physics hack.

- By Thief games I mean Thief: The Dark Project and Thief: Metal Age and their mods.
- I remember it involved abusing game physics, it should work on clean installation of Thief  (it was not done by console command or by some user script, game trainer or something similar).
- I remember, possibly incorrectly, it involved grabbing item (You had in inventory?), hoisting on it, jumping of it, hoisting, jumpig of it ... and it elevated You
- You had to have at least 2 items with which You did it, I think
- I imagine it looked similar to [how somobody skipped final sequence in Oblivion speedrun (contains spoilers!)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfmdl9-tnSU#t=8m12s) .

Do You know how it worked? And possibly why it worked?

Thanks:).

Comment: I'd just like to say that 'rembeber' is now my favourite word.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly there was a glitch in Thief that involved bunny hopping as you were running forward.  This allowed you to build up incredible speed, and because the distance you can jump in Thief was based on your movement speed, you can jump seemingly impossible jumps.

The most popular jump in the game was the tower jump in the Lost City level.

I believe this was fixed in Thief Gold and later Thief games.

I'm not sure if this is the correct glitch you are remembering though.

Comment: It was not the one but thanks:). It works because they let You build up speed (each jump adds speed, they don't check if You are already jumping or constrain the speed). AFAIK it came from Quake and even Doom had rocket jumps. But they are all about speed, my glitch is about height.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of crate stacking. To do this, you face straight down and jump, then drop a crate which you then land on. You repeat this process until you run out of crates. I'm not sure if you can get arbitrarily high this way though, but you can get pretty high! You might need to prepare a stack of crates next to where you want to do it, to grab once you are too high to grab the ones at ground level.